# Avoid AlertDialog auto dismissing when positive button is pressed

Tags: android, kotlin, button, dialog, dismiss

I am attempting to prevent the automatic dismissal of a dialog in the else statement in siteListFragment.kt, but despite my efforts, the dialog dismisses on its own.

Here is my code:
siteListFragment.kt

```
override fun showAddSiteDialog() {
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_site_add, null)
        DialogService.showWithView(
            requireContext(),
            DialogService.DialogType.INFO,
            false,
            getString(R.string.add_site),
            view,
            null,
            DialogService.TextWithCallback(getString(R.string.dialog_negative_cancel)){
                DialogService.dismiss()
            },
            DialogService.TextWithCallback(getString(R.string.dialog_positive_add)){
                GlobalScope.launch {
                    val editText = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.site_name_add)

                    val enteredText = editText.text.toString()
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        if (siteListPresenter.addSite(enteredText)) {
                            DialogService.dismiss()
                        } 
                        
                        //here
                        else {
                            editText.error = getString(R.string.network_update_error_empty_name_message)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

DialogService.kt

```
    private var dialog: AlertDialog? = null
    var builder:  AlertDialog.Builder? = null

private fun create(
        context: Context,
        dialogType: DialogType,
        cancelable: Boolean,
        title: String,
        message: String?
        ) {
        builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.CreativePodDialog)
        dialog = builder!!.create()
        builder!!.apply {
            setTitle(title)
            setIcon(getIcon(dialogType))

            if (message != null && message != "") setMessage(message)
            setCancelable(cancelable)
        }
    }

fun showWithView(
        context: Context,
        dialogType: DialogType,
        cancelable: Boolean,
        title: String,
        view: View? = null,
        negativeButton: TextWithCallback?,
        neutralButton: TextWithCallback?,
        positiveButton: TextWithCallback?,
    ) {
        create(context, dialogType, cancelable, title, null)

        builder!!.apply {
            setView(view)
            if (positiveButton != null)
                setPositiveButton(positiveButton.text) { _, _ ->
                    positiveButton.callback.invoke()
                }
            if (negativeButton != null)
                setNegativeButton(negativeButton.text) { _, _ ->
                    negativeButton.callback.invoke()
                }
            if (neutralButton != null)
                setNeutralButton(neutralButton.text) { _, _ ->
                    neutralButton.callback.invoke()
                }
        }.show()
    }
```

I have tried to set the dialog to not cancelable which allows you to press outside the dialog and not have it dismiss but doesnt effect the button. I have also tried to set the dialog positive button callback to null which just defaults to dismissing. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AlertDialog` by default has `View.onClickListener`s which will **automatically dismiss** the dialog once user clicks the positive or negative button.

To prevent this from happening, you'll have to **override** the listener yourself.

```
val btPositive = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
btPositive.setOnClickListener {
    // do something here
    // dialog won't be dismissed now!
}
```

You can pass **null** callback in the `DialogService.TextWithCallback` function to make it work as expected.

Comment: just as a note for this to work `val alertDialog = builder!!.apply { /* code here */ }.show()`

Comment: I would if I could but I can't as my reputation is not 15 or greater